# How ejs template is loaded on browser? How frontend interact with backend?

Tags: html, node.js, frontend, ejs, scriptlet

Working on frontend and backend using NodeJs for server side and ejs template for frontend. Came across a feature while using [ejs scriplets](http://www.ejs.co/#docs) to display data send from server while loading page.

Used `<%console.log()%>` over ejs, thought this log will be seen on inspect element logs, however got message over server terminal. How did this information is send over to server without any form submit or API call?

Server app.js:

```
  /*jshint multistr: true, node: true, esversion: 6, undef: true, unused: true, varstmt: true*/
  "use strict";

  // NPM Modules
  const express                     = require('express'),
        path                        = require('path');

  const app                         = express();

  // Setup views directory, file type and public filder.
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.render('index', {message:'Welcome'});
  });

  const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

  console.log('server listening at http://127.0.0.1 over port: ', port);

  app.listen(port);
```

EJS template index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!-- All these CSS files are in plublic directory, as we had made all the content of public directory available for anyone from app.js -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/app.css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo.jpg" />
        <title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%console.log(message)%>
        <%=message%>
        <%console.log("anything")%>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can all the `<%console.log()%>` are send over server terminal and `<%=message%>` is displayed over browser. Even `<%console.log("anything")%>` is displayed over server terminal even though this has nothing to do with server. How ejs scriplets communicate with server and not browser?

Had anyone else tried this before or observed it.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is about how ejs templates work.  This is an answer for that question.  I think you might also have something wonky going on with your express setup causing you problems.

EJS is a server-side rendering system.  It's job is done before the html is sent to the client, so it has nothing to do with the browser.

The scriptlets inside `<% %>` run on the server to insert content into the template before sending to the client.

If you want to print something out on the browser console, don't put it in a scriptlet, just put it into a `<script>` tag, like this:

```
<script>
    console.log("foo");
</script>
```

If you want the browser console to print something generated by the server, you could use ejs to put the value of message into what it generates:

```
<script>
    console.log("<%=message%>");
</script>
```

The server will put the value of message into a console.log() statement that gets delivered to the browser.

This example prints "Wellcomes" to the browser console:

server:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    express = require('express'),
    path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', { message: 'Wellcomes' });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const listener = app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('platform listening on', listener.address().port);
});
```

index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            console.log("<%=message %>");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you show page source in your browser, you should see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            console.log("Wellcomes");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you even tried it? Put it in `<script>` and you will get error `ReferenceError: Welcome is not defined`, where `Welcome` is what was passed in `message`. And this will still log into server terminal, not on browser console.

Comment: You didn't prune your example down a point where it's easy to test.  res.render() is experiencing an error so it's not getting to the client.

Comment: `<%=message%>` printed value over HTML on browser, when move this in `<script>` got error.

Comment: I just made a test case, and my example does work.  You problem might be in your server setup.